# Regex character repeats n or more times in line with grep

Tags: regex, grep, repeat

I need to find the regex expression to find a character that repeats 4 or more times with grep.

I know that the expression is {n,}, so if I need to find lines, for example, when the character "g" repeats 4 or more times, in theory with grep man page is:

```
grep "g{4,}" textsamplefile
```

But doesn't work. Any help?

The character could have other letters. For example, a valid match is:

**g**example**g**of**g**valid**g**match**g**

**g**other**g**valid**g**match**g**is**g**here**g**

**gggg**other

Comment: Use `grep "g\{4,\}" textsamplefile` or `grep -E "g{4,}" textsamplefile`

Comment: Hello Wiktor. That's doesn't work

Comment: Using SunOS? Then use `grep "ggggg*" textsamplefile`. Limiting quantifiers do not work there. Or install the GNU grep version.

Comment: Could you please give us your OS name/version `uname -a` and your grep version `grep -V`?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu LTS 16.04, grep 2.25

Comment: GNU grep right? that's really strange because it's working on my environment and I have the same OS/distribution and the same version of grep...

Comment: @Goncatin If `grep "ggggg*" textsamplefile` does not work, the problem is not with `grep`.

Comment: @Wiktor: It looks like the requirements have changed lol

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you should change your `grep` command in:

```
grep -E 'g{4,}' input_file # --> this will extract only the lines containing chains of 4 or more g
```

if you want to take all the lines that contain chains of 4 or more identical characters your regex become:

```
grep -E '(.)\1{3,}' input_file
```

If you **do not need the chains** but only line where `g` appear 4 or more times:

```
grep -E '([^g]*g){4}' input_file
```

you can **generalize** to any char repeating 4 times or more by using:

```
grep -E '(.)(.*\1){3}' input_file
```

Comment: I'm not looking for chains, only the lines when the character repeats. For example, a valid match must be exgentgougligshg

Comment: can you try the last regex and let me know if it works?

Comment: @Goncatin Use `'([^g]*g){4}'` ERE pattern.

Comment: @Wiktor: Thanks for the tip, I have edited the answer!
However, would it be possible to generalize it for any character not only `g`? 
I have tried to find a general regex but I couldn't get one...

Comment: edited so that it can take any char that appear 4 times or more in the line at any place